# Android Layout Can't get EditText to line up in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I created a layout for dialog box.  I want same width for zip code EditText and Email EditText Edit boxes and I want them to align left.

So it should look like:

Email:     ***_*__*_*___**

ZipCode: ***_*__*_*___**

Correction: Actually above is not showing correctly on StackOverflow.  The lines above should be exactly even and left justified.  So I have exactly the same display problem on this forum.  I put spaces after Email: but it still does not align.

Instead I am getting email always wider than Zip code.  I even changed both EditText to same input type but no luck.  Only if the TextView has exactly the same text do they align like if they both say Zip Code:.  If I pad Email text edit with spaces they layout manager seems to know this and expand the email EditText larger than for the zip code. Very frustrating!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/messageMsg"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_21px"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="lorum ipsum afasdf lajsdfasldfjald:"
    android:padding="10dip"
    />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView   
        android:id="@+id/emailDescriptor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_21px"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
           android:padding="10dip"              
           android:text="Email:    "/>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/emailId"
         android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
           android:layout_margin="10dip"            
           android:textSize="@dimen/text_21px" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">   
    <TextView   
        android:id="@+id/zipCodeDescript"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_21px"
        android:text="ZIP Code: "
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/zCode"
         android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_21px"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, then why don't you just hardcode the `dp` of the TextViews?

Answer (score 0):

As @AedonEtLIRA said, you can hardcode the position. You could increase the margin attribute for the left side to make them align.

Alternatively, you could use the attribute,

```
android:layout_alignLeft="@id/your_other_edittext"
```

A third idea, make the text boxes for your labels the same "width", then the following edittexts should align.

Finally, you could use weighted nests layouts. But that is a bad idea. Poor performance & excessively confusing. =)

Comment: android:layout_alignLeft not avail for LinearLayout

Comment: How do you make them the same width?

Comment: Set their "width" attributes to the same number for the label boxes.  Are you using a 4 boxes or 2? I was assuming 4 boxes: 2 text box labels & 2 edittext entry fields.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Email" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
            android:text="ZipCode" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: `android:layout_weight="1"` instead `android:ems="10"` will make the `EditText` using the left space instead setting it to a fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon a useful attribute today and remembered this post.

Check out [Textview.setEms(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setEms%28int%29). Edittext inherits that function as well.